# How to get the graph for covid-death per capita for specific countries?

Tags: covid19

I am looking for a source that allows me to perform the logarithmic chart of COVID-19 Deaths per capita for selected countries with up-to-date data as below

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your concern is right here

https://ourworldindata.org/covid-deaths

You can choose the countries based on your desires.